# Cant write blob with key

Tags: angular, azure, blob

I have a problem to write into azure Storage Container blob. I post http put a request for azure site in angular. I have tried different keys including SAS.

I always get error 403:
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

```
so I suppose the url was found 
can you please help me

the code is as follows

let url = "https://matasisrael.blob.core.windows.net/matas/routes.json";
const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'x-ms-version': '2015-02-21',
        'x-ms-date': '2019-04-09',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'Authorization': 'SharedKey myaccount:<access key>,

        'Vary': 'Origin',
        'Content-Length':"1024"

      })
    };
     this.http.put(url,"{hel:ds}",httpOptions).subscribe(data=> {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're uploading blob through an Angular app, it is recommended that you use SAS Token. With SAS Token you don't really need to provide `Authorization` header.

What you will do is create the SAS Url using the blob URL and SAS Token and do an HTTP PUT request using that URL. Since the SAS Token already contains the storage service version, you don't need to include `x-ms-version` in your request headers. Also, you don't need `x-ms-date` header.

So your code would be something like:

```
let url = "https://matasisrael.blob.core.windows.net/matas/routes.json?" + sasToken;
let requestBody = "{hel:ds}";
const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'Content-Length': requestBody.length
      })
    };
this.http.put(url, requestBody, httpOptions).subscribe(data=> {})
```